# What is the best way to get a trigger at the moment a software installation wizard starts?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I am looking for a convenient way to recognize a software installation wizard has started to run on windows. (Should work with any type of installation, not only Msi for example).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is impossible with the scope that you mention.  MSI could be detected by the creation of a mutex but other installation types would use different techniques and is not detectable.

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no common "action" each installation should make in order to install the software on windows no matter what kind of installation type is chosen?

Comment: Correct.  Most (but not all) will update Add/Remove Programs but that's not until the install is finished.  I've seen people create PowerShell/VBS/.BAT files and call them installers.  Installers can install a variety of things so there is no one way to detect them.

Comment: Well what is the best way to do it if we are talking about msi installer for now?

Comment: Check for the creation of the _MSIExecute Mutex. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372909(v=vs.85).aspx  The problem is MSI only has 80% of corp market and 40% of consumer market.  Developers are still doing things any which way they want.

Comment: Did not help. Any other ideas?

Comment: One of the products my company sells uses "XCOPY Installation" - they copy the files to the user system, configure the server portion of the app and bingo! the product's installed.  Delete the files and the product's uninstalled.  There's no way to automatically detect that "installation" according to your requirement.